# How the contents of a directory are impacted when a file system is mounted on that directory

Tags: filesystems, mount

How the contents of a directory are impacted (and when and/or if they are available for use) when a file system is mounted on that directory.

Comment: Thanks !!! Makes since and thanks for the link for the question

Answer (score 0):

The answers to [this superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/200685/what-does-linux-do-with-existing-files-in-a-mount-point) should answer your question.

A few selected quotes:

> It will just be mounted, and the files disappear, coming back when the folder is umounted.
>
> ...
>
> It works like a stack, if you mount something else, it hides the previous content. When you unmount, the previous stuff becomes visible again.
>
> ...
>
> Under Linux, there is a way to see the hidden files.  You can use `mount --bind` to get another view of the filesystem where the mount point is. For example...
>
> ...

Comment: makes since and thanks for the quick response